# Powershell: how can I get just the text of a property?

Tags: powershell

I want to get current working directory in powershell, which I do with `pwd` which gives me output like:

```
Path
----
C:\Users\Ian\source\repos\python\Modules\Hub
```

However I want to copy this to the clipboard with `pwd | clip` but the output with the header doesn't really paste nicely into single line text fields.

How do I get just the path (e.g. "C:\Users\Ian\source\repos\python\Modules\Hub")?

I tried `pwd | Select-Object -Property Path | clip` but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with:

```
pwd | foreach {$_.Path} | clip
```

I'm hoping there's a more concise way however.

Comment: `$(pwd).toString() | clip`

Comment: alternately (and more "powershell-y") `$(pwd).Path | clip`

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks! For the second idea especially. If the question wasn't closed I would have accepted that as an answer.